# IssueFactory.getIssue() creates an issue with id == null

Tags: java, groovy, jira, jira-plugin

Hi I was using adaptavist scriptrunner to create a small script that creates a subtask:

```
ApplicationUser user   = // .. obtaining the user
MutableIssue parent = // .. obtaining parent issue
MutableIssue child  = issueFactory.getIssue()

// ... filling child with some data

// here the errors appear:
// workflow error
Issue subtask = issueManager.createIssueObject(user, child)
// null pointer
subTaskManager.createSubTaskIssueLink(parent, child, user)
```

I was trying to figure out what's wrong, and looks like I found the problem:
child.getId() returns null. Did I miss something? Should `getIssue()` return an empty issue without id?

Jira version 7.1.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

- Use [IssueService.validateSubtaskCreate](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/latest/com/atlassian/jira/bc/issue/IssueService.html#validateSubTaskCreate-com.atlassian.jira.user.ApplicationUser-java.lang.Long-com.atlassian.jira.issue.IssueInputParameters-) to validate your input parameters.
- Use the validationResult that the previous method returned to call [IssueService.create](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/latest/com/atlassian/jira/bc/issue/IssueService.html#create-com.atlassian.jira.user.ApplicationUser-com.atlassian.jira.bc.issue.IssueService.CreateValidationResult-).
- Use [SubtaskManager.createSubtaskIssueLink](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/latest/com/atlassian/jira/config/SubTaskManager.html#createSubTaskIssueLink-com.atlassian.jira.issue.Issue-com.atlassian.jira.issue.Issue-com.atlassian.jira.user.ApplicationUser-) to link the parent and subtask issue like you already do.

There's also [this related question on Atlassian Answers](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/96765/create-subtask-with-java-plugin) that has some sample code.

Answer (score 0):

```
MutableIssue child  = issueFactory.getIssue()
// issueFactory.getIssue(), returns an instance of MutableIssue, 
// that will be used to set issue data, here issue is not yet created
// in jira yet hence issue id and key will be null here
// ...

Issue subtask = issueManager.createIssueObject(user, child)
// issueManager.createIssueObject(user, child), creates the issue
// in the jira and after execution of this statement, you can retrieve
// issue id and issue key
```